# Trying to REopen Sytem.IO Objects

Tags: c#, streamreader, streamwriter, system.io.file

I am making a program that allows you to roll five different types of multi sided "dice", and when you roll a number I want it to store it in a text file. There is a menu strip item at the top of my form that you click, it closes the StreamWriter and FileStream and opens a second form showing what numbers were rolled and by what die they were rolled ( I'm having it be just the numbers rolled now for simplicity's sake) and it displays fine. But when I close the Reader, Stream, and second form and go back to the first form, I try to Reopen the Writer and Stream and it tells me that is already in use.

My First Form's Code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Random ran = new Random();
        static FileStream outFile = new FileStream(@"H:\C#\Independant Projects\VirtualDice\History.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(outFile);

        private int ranNum;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ranNum = ran.Next(1, 21);
            Display();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ranNum = ran.Next(1, 13);
            Display();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ranNum = ran.Next(1, 5);
            Display();
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ranNum = ran.Next(1, 9);
            Display();
        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ranNum = ran.Next(1, 11);
            Display();
        }
        private void Display()
        {
            lblNum.Text = String.Format("{0}", ranNum);
            lblNum.Visible = true;
            writer.WriteLine(ranNum);
        }

        private void historyToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 1;
            writer.Close();
            outFile.Close();
            History history = new History();
            history.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FileStream outFile = new FileStream(@"H:\C#\Independant Projects\VirtualDice\History.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(outFile);
            tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

My Second Form's Code:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class History : Form
    {
        public History()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        static private FileStream inFile = new FileStream(@"H:\C#\Independant Projects\VirtualDice\History.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        private StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(inFile);

        private void History_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string item;

            item = reader.ReadLine();
            try
            {
                lstHistory.Items.Add(item);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                lstHistory.Font = new Font(lstHistory.Font.Name, 12, lstHistory.Font.Unit);
                lstHistory.Items.Add("You have not rolled any numbers");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to release the unmanaged resources (in your case the file) properly once done with it. Call the `Dispose()` function on the `stream` once done with it:

```
if(inFile != null){
    inFile.Dispose();
}
```

And even better, wrap it in a `using()` like this:

```
using(FileStream outFile = new FileStream(@"H:\C#\Independant Projects\VirtualDice\History.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write)){
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(outFile);
    tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

`using` will automatically call `Dispose()` for you at the right time in the proper way (i.e. it checks if the object is `null` first before calling `Dispose()` on it to avoid a `null exception). Check [this link for more details about the using statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx).

However, if you have the same code in so many places, it is probably worth it to wrap it in a `singleton` pattern. Check [this Microsoft article on how to write a singleton pattern in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx).

Comment: Is there a using statement I need to use, because I can't find the singleton keyword? Also the other two solutions didn't work for me.

Comment: What are the other two solution that didn't work for you? The singleton is a pattern not a language syntax. It is like putting all the functionality of opening, reading and writing to the file in one class and call its functions anywhere you want in code. Check the link I provided to learn how to implement and use the pattern. As for the `using`, yes it is a statement in C# and you can read more about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx).